# How do I get the super key working properly in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with emacs 23.

When I am in org-mode and I hold down control, windows key and hit return, I see:
"C-s-return is undefined"

In org-mode it tells me that C-S-RET will insert a new TODO entry which is what I want.

How do I get the super key to work properly? (assuming that is the problem - not sure why its displaying the small S rather than the capital but I am guessing that is something to do with it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to the capital/lower case `S`.

`S` as a modifier refers to `Shift` whereas `s` refers to `super`.

`C-S-RET` means `Ctrl+Shift+RET` in this case (and others referencing `C-S-<key>` rather than `Ctrl+super+RET`.